C# xaml - CheckBox no se a podido convertir a MenuItem Error
Hola se para y me da CheckBox no se a podido convertir a MenuItem Error... y no hay forma... ya hace tiempo que tengo este source y soy un principiante en esto de la programación, no tengo ni idea de por que no para al ejecutar.
¿Alguien sabe el por que y como resolverlo?
              </MenuItem>
            </ContextMenu>
          </FrameworkElement.ContextMenu>
          <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn DataGridColumn.Header="#" DataGridColumn.MinWidth="30" DataGridBoundColumn.Binding="{Binding SlNo}"
                                DataGridBoundColumn.ClipboardContentBinding="{x:Null}"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn DataGridColumn.Header="URL" DataGridColumn.Width="*" DataGridBoundColumn.Binding="{Binding URL}"
                                DataGridBoundColumn.ClipboardContentBinding="{x:Null}"/>
          </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
        <TextBox x:Name="TBUrl" FrameworkElement.Height="23" FrameworkElement.Margin="10,31,109,0"
                 TextWrapping="NoWrap" FrameworkElement.VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
        <TextBlock x:Name="textBlock8" FrameworkElement.HorizontalAlignment="Left" FrameworkElement.Margin="10,10,0,0"
                   TextWrapping="Wrap" FrameworkElement.VerticalAlignment="Top">
          <Run Text="URL:"/>
          <Run Text=" "/>
          <Run Text="*"/>
        </TextBlock>
        <CheckBox x:Name="CBoxMtchURL" ContentControl.Content="Match URL"
                  FrameworkElement.HorizontalAlignment="Right" FrameworkElement.Margin="0,82,10,0"
                  FrameworkElement.VerticalAlignment="Top" FrameworkElement.Width="81" ToggleButton.IsChecked="True"/>
        <Button x:Name="BTClose" ContentControl.Content="Close" FrameworkElement.HorizontalAlignment="Right"
...

en csharp
void IComponentConnector.Connect(int connectionId, object target)
    {
...
        case 6:
            ((System.Windows.Controls.MenuItem)target).Click += MenuClearURL_Click;
            break;
        case 7:
            textBox_0 = (System.Windows.Controls.TextBox)target;
            break;
        case 8:
            textBlock_0 = (TextBlock)target;
            break;
        case 9:
            checkBox_0 = (System.Windows.Controls.CheckBox)target;
            break;
        case 10:
            button_0 = (System.Windows.Controls.Button)target;
            button_0.Click += BTClose_Click;
            break;
        case 11:
            image_0 = (Image)target;
            image_0.MouseMove += ImageInfo_MouseMove;
            image_0.MouseLeave += ImageInfo_MouseLeave;
...

Espero que alguien me responda pronto. Gracias... Un saludo

Podrias aclarar un monton el problema.. en que linea se da el error? donde esta esa conversion? que es ese codigo? que se supone que hace?
